# Can we create a jumbled table using pandas dataframe?

Tags: r, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

Tables are usually having m rows and n columns. But can we create jumbled table in python ?

Like:

```
1  2  3
4  5
6  7  8  9
```

R programming language have a functionality which automatically filled the blank or uninitialized cell with 'NA'. For example, If we make above table in R, It will look like:

```
1  2  3  NA
4  5  NA NA
6  7  8  9
```

R will automatically create m rows by largest columns Table.
Largest column means if we add one more row having more columns than the existing table then R will automatically create the new column and initialize the new column for previous rows with 'NA'.
For example, If we add `[A, B, C, D, E, F]` as my new row. Then the result in R will be :

```
1  2  3  NA NA NA
4  5  NA NA NA NA
6  7  8  9  NA NA
A  B  C  D  E  F
```

So, **do we have that kind of functionality in python** ?

Comment: pandas add `NaN`s same way.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, pandas does the same thing. For instance, here's an example of  concatenating two dataframes with different lengths column-wise:

```
>>> import pandas as pd 
>>> df = pd.DataFrame({"A":[1,2,3],"B":[2,65,4]})
>>> df
   A   B
0  1   2
1  2  65
2  3   4
>>> df1 = pd.DataFrame({"C":[1,2,3,5],"D":[2,65,4,8]})
>>> df1
   C   D
0  1   2
1  2  65
2  3   4
3  5   8
>>> pd.concat([df, df1], axis=1)
     A     B  C   D
0  1.0   2.0  1   2
1  2.0  65.0  2  65
2  3.0   4.0  3   4
3  NaN   NaN  5   8
>>>
```

As you can see, pandas fills in the third row with `NaN` for the shorter columns `A` and `B`.

The same can be seen when concatenating along the rows, for example:

```
>>> df2 = pd.DataFrame({"A":[5,8,4,9],"B":[8,6,9,4],"C":[4,6,8,2]})
>>> df2
   A  B  C
0  5  8  4
1  8  6  6
2  4  9  8
3  9  4  2
>>> df 
   A   B
0  1   2
1  2  65
2  3   4
>>> pd.concat([df, df2], axis=0)
   A   B    C
0  1   2  NaN
1  2  65  NaN
2  3   4  NaN
0  5   8  4.0
1  8   6  6.0
2  4   9  8.0
3  9   4  2.0
>>>
```

Answer (score 2):

Just pass a list of lists to the constructor.

---

```
pd.DataFrame([[1, 2, 3], [4, 5], [6, 7, 8, 9]], dtype=float)

     0    1    2    3
0  1.0  2.0  3.0  NaN
1  4.0  5.0  NaN  NaN
2  6.0  7.0  8.0  9.0
```

---

And add a new row

```
df = pd.DataFrame([[1, 2, 3], [4, 5], [6, 7, 8, 9]], dtype=float)
df.append(pd.Series([2.1, 3.4, 5.6, 0.1, 7.5, 9.3], name=3))

     0    1    2    3    4    5
0  1.0  2.0  3.0  NaN  NaN  NaN
1  4.0  5.0  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
2  6.0  7.0  8.0  9.0  NaN  NaN
3  2.1  3.4  5.6  0.1  7.5  9.3
```

Comment: plus1, it is much better ;)